# In Makefile why my phony target is execute between two different generic rule

Tags: gnu-make

My problem is as follows:

I have two targets in my Makefile, toad4 and toad5.

Depending on which target is built some different files and compiler flags need to be set.

This works for the actual build and goes like this:

```
SDCC = /Volumes/Partition2/Users/nyholku/sdcc340/bin/sdcc

SDCCFLAGS = "-Wl -f 0xffff" -DTOAD_HW_VERSION=${HWVERSION} --verbose --no-crt --ivt-loc=0x800 -V -L /Volumes/Partition2/Users/nyholku/sdcc340/non-free/lib/pic16 -Wa,-S,0 -Wl,-m,-s18f45k50.lkr -mpic16 -p18f45k50 --disable-warning 85 --std-sdcc99 --obanksel=3 --use-non-free

.PHONY: toad4
toad4: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex
toad4: HI_SPEED_IRQ_ASM :=hi_speed_irq-hw4.asm
toad4: HWVERSION := HW4
toad4: BOOTLOADER := ../diolan-plus2-toad4/fw/bootloader.hex

.PHONY: toad5
toad5: HI_SPEED_IRQ_ASM :=hi_speed_irq.asm
toad5: HWVERSION := HW5
toad5: BOOTLOADER := ../diolan-plus2-toad5/fw/bootloader.hex
toad5: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $$(@D)/.f
    @echo $(PATH)
    $(SDCC) -c $(SDCCFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

But later in the Make file I have rule to produce the C code dependencies:

```
# First include the dependencies
include $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS:.c=.dep))

# Then recreate them
$(OBJDIR)/%.dep: %.c $$(@D)/.f
     set -e; rm -f $@; \
      $(SDCC) -c -M $(SDCCFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
      sed -e '1 s,^,$(OBJDIR)/,' -e 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
```

This was adapted from the GNU Makefile manual and worked before I introduced the dual target scheme.

When I comment that dependency generation out, the make works, the flag HWVERSION gets set for the C compilation (through the SDCCFLAGS), just as they it should,  depending on the target.

But if I leave that dependency generation in then apparently that rule is applied before the toad4 and toad5 rules because the HWVERSION is empty and the C-compilation to produce the dependencies fails.

So why is the other generic C compile rule applied before the toad4/toad5 rules and the dependency generating rules is applied before?

I'm also ok with suggestion on how to organise this better for the goal of building to different binaries from mostly same files with different settings. This should be quite common need.

I'm using GNU Make 3.81 on macOS 11.3.1 and the compiler is Small Device C Compiler ie SDCC

For completeness the complete Make file is here

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Copyright (c) 2011, Kustaa Nyholm / SpareTimeLabs
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
# are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
#
# Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list
# of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#
# Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this
# list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other
# materials provided with the distribution.
#
# Neither the name of the Kustaa Nyholm or SpareTimeLabs nor the names of its
# contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
# without specific prior written permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
# AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
# WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.
# IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT,
# INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT
# NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA,
# OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY,
# WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
# ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY
# OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
# Everyone should have this
.SUFFIXES:

# The output file name
TARGET = toad4

# This is necessary so that pk2cmd (used by 'load' script) is found and for the
# pk2cmd to find its support files (it seems to search current dir which is wrong)
PATH := ${PATH}

UPLOADER := java -cp ~/EazyCNC-Project/classes:/Volumes/Partition2/Users/nyholku/EazyCNC-Project/lib/purejavahidapi-0.0.12.jar:/Volumes/Partition2/Users/nyholku/EazyCNC-Project/lib/jna-5.6.0.jar diolanupdater.UpdateFirmware
ENCODER := /Volumes/Partition2/Users/nyholku/diolan-plus2/encoder/build/encoder
HEXMATE :=  /Applications/microchip/xc8/v2.32/pic/bin/hexmate



# The source files that make up the project go here

SRCS = main.c toad4.c usb_hid.c usb_core.c usb_pic_defs.c usb_user_config.c command_queue.c crt0iz_toad4.c swuart.c

# The libraries that are used go here
LIBS =  libc18f.lib libm18f.lib libsdcc.lib

# Where to find the compiler
SDCC = /Volumes/Partition2/Users/nyholku/sdcc340/bin/sdcc

# Compiler flags go here
# --use-crt=crt0.o            TOAD_HW_VERSION
SDCCFLAGS = "-Wl -f 0xffff" -DTOAD_HW_VERSION=${HWVERSION} --verbose --no-crt --ivt-loc=0x800 -V -L /Volumes/Partition2/Users/nyholku/sdcc340/non-free/lib/pic16 -Wa,-S,0 -Wl,-m,-s18f45k50.lkr -mpic16 -p18f45k50 --disable-warning 85 --std-sdcc99 --obanksel=3 --use-non-free

# Where to store the target/intermediate/temporary/object files
OBJDIR = ../obj
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
.PHONY: toad4
toad4: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex
toad4: HI_SPEED_IRQ_ASM :=hi_speed_irq-hw4.asm
toad4: HWVERSION := HW4
toad4: BOOTLOADER := ../diolan-plus2-toad4/fw/bootloader.hex

.PHONY: toad5
toad5: HI_SPEED_IRQ_ASM :=hi_speed_irq.asm
toad5: HWVERSION := HW5
toad5: BOOTLOADER := ../diolan-plus2-toad5/fw/bootloader.hex
toad5: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex
#

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.PHONY: load
load:
    $(UPLOADER) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET)-encoded.hex
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.PHONY: comparebootloaders
comparebootloaders:
    $(HEXMATE) -o$../bootloader-backedp.hex -fill=0xFF@0x0000:0x07FF r0000-07FF,/Volumes/Partition2/Users/nyholku/diolan-plus2/fw-backup-25.7.2017/bootloader.hex r000802-FFFFFF,/Volumes/Partition2/Users/nyholku/diolan-plus2/fw-backup-25.7.2017/bootloader.hex
    $(HEXMATE) -o$../bootloader-toad4.hex -fill=0xFF@0x0000:0x07FF r0000-07FF,../diolan-plus2-toad4/fw/bootloader.hex r000802-FFFFFF,../diolan-plus2-toad4/fw/bootloader.hex
    $(HEXMATE) -o$../bootloader-toad5.hex -fill=0xFF@0x0000:0x07FF r0000-07FF,../diolan-plus2-toad5/fw/bootloader.hex r000802-FFFFFF,../diolan-plus2-toad5/fw/bootloader.hex
#
#
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# This ensures that the object directory exists and re-creates it if necessary
#
# This requires make 3.81 or later, delete this section and all expressions that
# refer to .f if you have an older make
#
.SECONDEXPANSION:

# Uses a .f file as a flag file in each directory
%/.f:
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    touch $@

# dont' let make remove the flag files automatically
.PRECIOUS: %/.f
#
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Actual rules
#
# Compile the C-files
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $$(@D)/.f
    @echo $(PATH)
    $(SDCC) -c $(SDCCFLAGS) $< -o $@

 KEY=${TOAD4PLUS_DIALON_KEY2}

# Link the compiled files and libraries
$(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex: $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS:.c=.o))  $(OBJDIR)/hi_speed_irq.o
    $(SDCC) $(SDCCFLAGS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS:.c=.o)) $(LIBS) $(OBJDIR)/hi_speed_irq.o
# normalize the code filling un-used code memory with 0xFF so that encoding always works on known data
    $(HEXMATE) -o$(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET)-normalized.hex -fill=0xFF@0x0800:0x7FFF r0800-7FFF,$(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex
# sanitise the bootloader by keeping only the first 2kB (there is an extra jump code at 0x800 which overlaps with firmware code)
    $(HEXMATE) -o$(OBJDIR)/bootloader-normalized.hex -fill=0xFF@0x0000:0x07FF r0000-07FF,$(BOOTLOADER) r000802-FFFFFF,$(BOOTLOADER)
# combine the bootloader and firmware to one hex file that can be programmed with pickit ready to run
    $(HEXMATE) -o$(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET)-pickit.hex -fill=0xFFFF@0xF00001:0xF000FF -fill=0xA5@0xF00000:0xF00000 -fill=0x00@0x300000:0x30000D $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET)-normalized.hex ../obj/bootloader-normalized.hex
# encode the bootloader for bootloading purposes, suppress output so as NOT to reveal the secret key
    $(ENCODER) -ix $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET)-normalized.hex -ox $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET)-encoded.hex -e ${TOAD4PLUS_DIALON_KEY2}
# upload the encoded hex file using the bootload process
    $(UPLOADER) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET)-encoded.hex

# Compile the high speed interrupt asm file
$(OBJDIR)/hi_speed_irq.o: ${HI_SPEED_IRQ_ASM}
    gpasm -D TOAD_HW_VERSION=${HWVERSION} -o $(OBJDIR)/hi_speed_irq.o -c ${HI_SPEED_IRQ_ASM}

#
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Automatic generation of dependencies
#
# This magic code fragment from GNU make manual uses the SDCC compiler -M option
# to create a Makefile fragment for each C-source file describing the dependencies.
#
# Traditionally these fragments have the type '.d' but SDCC seems to delete them
# when it compiles files, so I use '.dep' here.
#
# Also SDCC '-M' option produces wrong dependency for the file being compiled
# in the sense that it does not contain the path, only the filename. Hence
# the 'sed' command has been mangled to inject the missing path to the fragment.
#

# First include the dependencies
include $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS:.c=.dep))

# Then recreate them
$(OBJDIR)/%.dep: %.c $$(@D)/.f
     set -e; rm -f $@; \
      $(SDCC) -c -M $(SDCCFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
      sed -e '1 s,^,$(OBJDIR)/,' -e 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# pretty standard default target
#
all:    toad5
#
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# pretty standard clean that attempts to delete all that this Makefile may left behind
#
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.rel
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.lnk
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.S19
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.map
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.mem
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.asm
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.rst
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.sym
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.lst
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.o
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.dep
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.hex
#
# cleanall deletes all in the object directory, do not use this if target dir == source dir
cleanall:
    rm $(OBJDIR)/*

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target-specific variable inheritance flows through the prerequisite dependency graph.  That's what you're relying on here: when a target is built as a prerequisite of `toad4` it gets one set of options and when it's built as a prerequisite of `toad5` it gets a different set of options.

However, when you are building the dependency file the recipe isn't run as a prerequisite of either `toad4` or `toad5`: as described in the manual the dependency file is built by make as part of parsing the makefile, because you `include`d those dependency files.  Because of that, none of the target-specific variables are set.

Stepping back it's not clear to me how you imagine this will work anyway.  You have two different sets of prerequisites but you are trying to keep them both in the same file: that can't ever work.  The only way it would be correct is if you rebuilt all the prerequisites every time you invoked make, so that they would be accurate for whatever target this particular make would want to build, but then of course everything in the makefile would be out of date and so everything would be rebuilt every time.

The right answer for a makefile that wants to build two different sets of targets from the same makefile, is to build two *different* sets of targets, not the same set of targets with different flags.  Specifically, you should have two different object directories and put the generated files from one build in one object directory (say, `obj-toad4`) and the generated files from the other build in the other object directory (say, `obj-toad5`).  Then they won't get mixed up and make can tell which are out of date and which are not.

Also, the method of handling automatic prerequisites described in the GNU make manual is out of date.  You should consider the method described here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: Thanks. This was a bit of hack, I know. My plan was to use 'make clean' everytime  I build for different target (which is rare), but I guess I should Do The Right Thing(tm) as you suggested. What put me off is the repetition that this causes in the Makefile, in other words, I am not competent enough to create rules that would apply to both targets.

Comment: BTW the modern method of generating dependencies you linked to cannot be used as-is, AFAIU, with SDCC because giving -M or -MM to SDCC causes it not to compile the code, it just runs the preprocessor.

Comment: If you want to run make clean etc. in between then the best thing to do is not use target-specific variables, but instead have a target that does something like create an included makefile containing the settings for the variables you want.  Then you'd run `make toad4` and it would delete `obj` then create `obj/config.mk` containing variable assignments for `toad4` and all builds would be for `toad4` until you ran `make toad5` which would delete `obj` and create `obj/config.mk` containing variable assignments for `toad5`, etc.

Comment: You don't have to duplicate all the rules; there are ways to avoid it.  One straightforward way is to have `make toad4` run a recursive make like `$(MAKE) all TARGET=toad4` then in your makefile use `$(TARGET)` attached to the `OBJDIR` value.

Comment: Regarding SDCC, while it's more efficient to have the compiler generate the dependency file in one step it's not required to use the new method.  You just need to have the dependency files generated in the same recipe as the compile; make doesn't know or care if it's done by executing one command line or more than one.  I believe that page has an example of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've now rewritten the Makefile along the lines suggested in http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/